# ActiveMQ - Kahadb log files will not clear

Tags: activemq-classic, kahadb

I've been tasked with investigating why the db-*.log files are not clearing.

From what I have found through vast searching, everything points to the messages being on the queue still. I've looked at hawtio at the queues on all the configured topics and the queue size is zero.

From my understanding the Enqueue size and Dequeue size in theory should be the same, but they're not. Seems my Dequeue size is 0.

I've looked at the topics and there's no operation to purge them.

I'd like to be able to clear out all messages so that the kahadb logs will disappear.

Comment: You need to add more specifics.  Since this seems to be Topics you are using you need to define what you are doing since messages on Topics are fire and forget unless durable subscriptions are in play.

Comment: Did you set any expiration for all your messages, or you have message that never expires as well?

Answer (score 4):

I think you point on one weakness of the ActiveMQ itself: it cannot guarantee the consumers are really strict when consuming the messages.

We have similar problems with our ActiveMQ (5.10.7) because it seems the KahaDB make likes a "disk fragmentation" and we noticed this could be from at least two issues with consumers:

**Case 1: Slow consumer**

We have in our system a consumer which cannot consume many messages at once. if only one unconsumed message stays in a KahaDB page, it will keep all the whole page (with all others messages which are already consumed, and acknowledged).
        For preventing the KahaDB Storage to reach 100% (which will slows the producers) we transfer the messages in another ActiveMQ instance temporary queue like this:

```
from("activemqPROD:queue:BIG_QUEUE_UNCONSUMED")
    .to("activemqTEMP:queue:TEMP_BIG_QUEUE");
```

then pushing them back:

```
from("activemqTEMP:queue:TEMP_BIG_QUEUE")
    .to("activemqPROD:queue:BIG_QUEUE_UNCONSUMED");
```

The alternative is to store them on file system then reload them, but you loose the JMS (and custom) headers. With the temporary queue solution you keep all headers.

**Case 2: Consumer who never gives acknowledgement**

Sometimes even we make the previous operation, even all unconsumed queues are empty, the storage stays higher than 0%. 
By looking into the KahaDB file we can see there are still pages present even no more messages in all QUEUES. 
For the TOPICS, we stopped using durable subscriptions, then the storage should also stays at 0%.

The potential cause (this is a supposition, but with a strong confidence) is that some of the consumed messages were never `acknowledged` properly.
The reason we think this is the cause, it is because in the logs, we can still see messages

```
"not removing data file: 12345 as contained ack(s) refer to referenced file: [12344, 12345]"
```

This can happens for example when the consumer is disconnecting abruptly (they consumed some messages but disconnect before sending the `ack`)
In our case the messages never expires, then this could also be a potential issue for this case. However it is not clear if setting an expiration can destroy "non-acked" messages.
Because we do not want to loose any event, there is no expiration time for these specific queues.

According to your question, it looks you are in the second case, then our solution is:

1. Be sure no more producer / consumer are connecting to the ActiveMQ
2. Be sure all queues and durable topics are empty
3. Delete all files in the KahaDB storage (from file system)
4. Restart ActiveMQ (fresh)

Unfortunately we did not find a better way to manage with these cases, if someone else have a better alternative we would be happy to know it.

[This article](https://uberdev.wordpress.com/2015/11/05/activemq-kahadb-journal-log-files-data-clean-up-problem/) can also give you some solution (like setting an expiry policy for the ActiveMQ.DLQ queue).

Answer (score 1):

add this log config to log4j.properties. Then you can see exactly what is holding kahadb files in kahadb.log.

```
log4j.appender.kahadb=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.kahadb.file=${activemq.base}/data/kahadb.log 
log4j.appender.kahadb.maxFileSize=1024KB 
log4j.appender.kahadb.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.kahadb.append=true
log4j.appender.kahadb.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.kahadb.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%-15.15t] %-5p %-30.30c{1}    - %m%n 
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase=TRACE, kahadb
```

Answer (score 0):

As alternative: once you've found out which Queue is causing the log to exist, you could map it to its own KahaDB like described here http://activemq.apache.org/kahadb.html